# populate document field in getter

Tags: mongoose, schema, getter, populate

I am trying to solve a problem where there are two fields on a schema that can conflict with each other. So the one field can be valid, but then once you consider the other it no longer is. It doesn't make sense to combine these two for a variety of reasons.

As a result, we have the option of either handling that comparison on the client or by implementing something lower-level to filter out invalid documents. i.e.

```
const schema = new Schema({
  isValid: Boolean,
  other: {
    isValid: Boolean
  }
})
```

if a document is not valid then it should be considered to be undefined

```
// assume these are the contents of the collection
const Raw = [
  {
     isValid: true,
     other: {
        isValid: true
     }
  },
  {
     isValid: false,
     other: {
        isValid: true
     }
  },
  {
     isValid: true,
     other: {
        isValid: false
     }
  },
]

const data = await schema.find({});

data.length === 1; // true
data[0] === Raw[0]; // true
```

Which is to say that I am trying to implement a getter for whenever you request a document that will check if the document is valid. In this particular case, though, `other` is instead an id to a different collection. So in order to determine if it's valid I would need to populate it.

What's the best way to go about that?

Comment: and what makes the other referenced document valid? You can use the $lookup in aggregation and fire a $match after that stage to check for it

Comment: mainly because I want to do this for any kind of access (including aggregations)

Answer (score 0):

I reconstructed the issue, make sure to replace the field names with what you have

This is the aggregation result: only one has both as true thus one document remains:
[image]

The aggregation as code looks like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'products', // The other collection
      'localField': 'otherId', // The matching field in this one
      'foreignField': '_id', // The matching field in products
      'as': 'otherId' // Overwrite otherId with the populated document
    }
  }, {
    '$match': { 
      'valid': 'true', // Match this fields value
      'otherId.valid': 'true' // Match the field from the other collection
    }
  }
])
```

Also Note, that $lookup always returns an array, chain it with $unwind if not wanted.

If the Database is very large you can do a match before and after to prevent unnecessary  lookups:

```js
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'valid': 'true'
    }
  }, {
    // ... lookup as above
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'otherId.valid': 'true'
    }
  }
]
```